# First popover showing outdated state

Tags: swift, swiftui, popover

I've found a to-my-taste weird behavior of popover. I want it to show a view with `PopoverItem` and `number`, both are to be set from `onTapGesture` in `ForEach`. The issue is that popover always shows the default `number` on first click, it works as expected for every other.

Wrong (left) and right behavior (on second click works as expected). Same on iOS, same with `Button`

[image: Text] [image: Text]

I was able to make it work with `Binding` but I'd like to find a better solution for presenting popovers and find out why it doesn't work as I expected.

My main view looks like this:

```
struct PopoverTest: View {
    let array: [PopoverItem] = [PopoverItem("First title"), PopoverItem("second title"), PopoverItem("third title")]
    @State var show: PopoverItem? = nil
    @State var number: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { number, item in
                MyPopover(number: number + 1, item: item)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.number = number + 1
                        self.show = item
                    }
            }
        }
        .popover(item: $show) { item in
            MyPopover(number: number, item: item)
        }
    }
}
```

and the popover and item:

```
struct MyPopover: View {
    let number: Int
    let item: PopoverItem
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(number)")
            Text(item.text)
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct PopoverItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let text: String
    
    init(_ text: String) { self.text = text }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The information *inside* popover passed **only via item**, ie in

```
.popover(item: $show) { item in
    MyPopover(number: number, item: item) // << number in only at init !!
}
```

so this case is invalid for popover

```
.onTapGesture {
    self.number = number + 1 // << changed only in state !!
    self.show = item        // passed in popover
}
```

so if you need `number` in `MyPopover`, you have to pass it via `item` by introducing new property in `PopoverItem` for it.

Comment: I thought so too but then – when you click on i.e. first title (doesn't work), then second (it works), then first again (it works). Why it works every time but not the first time?